# How do I implement marching cubes contouring on the geometry shader?

Tags: opengl

I have a uniformly sampled grid of distances:

D(x_i, y_j, z_k), where

x_i = x0 + i*dx, 0 <= i < nx

y_j = y0 + j*dy, 0 <= j < ny

z_k = z0 + k*dz, 0 <= k < nz

I want to pass each cell in this grid to the geometry shader and
output 0 to 5 triangles as specified in the marching cubes algorithm.

I was thinking sending x0, dx, y0, dy, z0, dz and the value to contour on to the shader using uniform values and encode the index of the cell as the position of a point:

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for(int i = 0; i < nx - 1; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < ny - 1; j++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < nz - 1; k++) {
            glVertex3f(i, j, k); 
        }
    }
}
glEnd();
```

Inside the geometry shader however I must look-up the distance values of the 8 corners in the (i,j,k) cell.
How can I pass the 3D array of distances to the geometry shader?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Even ignoring the fact that you're using immediate mode rendering, this kind of GS usage is going to be much slower than just doing it once on the CPU and rendering a nice, fast mesh.

Comment: Take a look at using a 3D texture for storing your grid data.  Here's a nice [article](http://www.icare3d.org/codes-and-projects/codes/opengl_geometry_shader_marching_cubes.html) describing the technique.

Comment: @NicolBolas While the immediate-mode point bit isn't optimal, if the application's going to change the isosurface value (as suggested in the OP), this seems like a great use for a GS.  Sending long lists of triangles to the GPU each frame won't be competitive with generating the geometry on the GPU (assuming that geometry shading is hardware accelerated, of course).

Comment: @radical7: "*Sending long lists of triangles to the GPU each frame won't be competitive with generating the geometry on the GPU*" GPUs are *designed* to process "long lists of triangles" efficiently. As for changing it every frame, the amount of data you'd be changing would be far from prohibitive for real-time applications. Unless you're rewriting every single cell every frame, you can always find ways to optimize the memory transfer. And it's not like upload speeds are incredibly slow these days. If you manage to make this work, you're going to be disappointed by the performance.

Comment: @NicolBolas GPU transform efficiency relies on the vertex data being GPU resident, as I believe you know.  While the OP never mentions any dataset sizes, consider a feasible scenario: given a 256^3 volume where 30% (to pick a number) of the voxels emit a single triangle (which is low-balling it - marching cubes can emit up to five tris per voxel), with 36 bytes/triangle yields 172 MB/frame in position-only vertex data.  At 60 Hz, that's over 10 GB/s.  PCIe 2.0 x16 @ 5GHz is only 8 GB/s.

Comment: @radical7: "*36 bytes/triangle*" There's no reason why you can't use 2-byte shorts for this. So you're already down to 18 bytes/triangle, which cuts the bandwidth in half. Also, you don't need 60fps for most uses of marching cubes; 30-20 is generally sufficient (and you certainly won't get 60fps with the method he's suggesting).

Comment: There are alot of videos on the web demoing voxel based terrain (on the gpu). E.g.: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkOA4udhHTc As far as I understand this is exactly marching cubes in realtime on the GPU.

Comment: @radical7: thanks for the link! This is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I am not going to use immediate mode in real life; it is just to explain briefly what I am doing. I will be using VBOs instead.